# Mountain Lion Mail using over 40GB of memory

Tags: macos, mail.app

Mail in Mountain Lion (10.8.3) seems to be having one heck of a memory leak.

[image]
As you can see, it's using over 44GB of memory and 200% CPU.

Machine specs:

- Mac Pro
- 2 x 2.4 GHz 6-Core Xeon
- 64GB RAM
- SSD drive

Comment: I assume you've already quit/killed Mail and restarted?

Comment: Yeah. Not a HUGE hit on performance, but the system as a whole is a little laggy (especially Mail.app itself).

Comment: @patrix Yeah, done that a few times. It's been doing this for a few days now.

Comment: "Usually" issues like that are related to a specific mail. Got any with an embedded video or so?

Comment: @patrix I have a few in my inbox that have attachments (.doc, .pdf, .png). But that's it. Maybe I should just suck it up and process the stuff in my inbox and see if that fixes it. :)

Comment: 6 Core Xeon, 64 GB RAM, SSD drive, and what fails is Mail? @_@.

Comment: How many accounts do you have? Maybe it's related to one specific account.

Comment: @ShaneHsu I have 5 accounts.

Comment: @Shpigford That could be a problem. Did any of those accounts have an incredibly large amount of emails?

Comment: Well all of them have many years worth of email...but the only "view" I'm ever in is "Inbox" which typically only has a couple dozen emails across all my accounts.

Comment: @Shpigford Also sample it. I think if you can pin down the reason for that high CPU usage, it should be the same for the incredibly high RAM usage. Also, is virtual memory enabled?